# Are RAID 1 disks usable transparently?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, mirror

I was wondering if RAID 1 disks are usable straight away, without the RAID controller. Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the RAID controller.

It if stores metadata on the discs, then obviously no. The RAID volume you see may be in a  partition the controller interprets.

That should be the norm today.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use an existing disk simply inserting it as the first disk in the RAID 1 array. Once in use, I would add the other disks

Comment: THe answer most likely is no.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and have experienced, you can't just take a disk which was once part of a RAID configuration and plug it in to any computer hoping that it can be used as any other disk.

Comment: And you tried that out with how many hundred different brands of raid controllers? Just to put SOME quantifiable information into your post.

Comment: Can't brag with quantities, but for the ones I've tried (MegaRAID/PERC, HighPoint, Linux Software Raid and a few others I can't name) this did not succeed.

Comment: Please notice that I'm pointing to RAID 1 (mirrors)